# Capybara::Poltergeist::MouseEventFailed. Poltergeist detected another element

Tags: ruby-on-rails, rspec, capybara

I am using capybara to test my button click function.

```
require 'spec_helper'

describe 'journals edition', js: true do

let(:update_button) { find('[name="commit"][value="Update"]') }

 describe 'redirection after update' do

 describe 'articles' do

  before :each do
    @journal = Journal.create(jid: '1')
  end

  it 'should redirect to detail' do
    visit dashboard_journal_path @journal
    update_button.trigger(:click)
    current_path.should eq dashboard_journals_path
  end

end
end
end
```

When I remove the div with class name 'rights_link' from my view,I am not getting the error

```
 Failure/Error: update_button.click
 Capybara::Poltergeist::MouseEventFailed:
   Firing a click at co-ordinates [45, 751] failed. Poltergeist detected another element with CSS selector 'html body footer div#footer div#login_info a' at this position. It may be overlapping the element you are trying to interact with. If you don't care about overlapping elements, try using node.trigger('click').
 # ./spec/features/journals/journal_edition_spec.rb:17:in `block (4 levels) in <top (required)>'
```

this is my view file

```
  h2 Journal #{@journal.id}

= errors_for @journal

div.show
  = form_for [:dashboard, @journal] do |f|
    div
  strong ID:
  br
  = @journal.id
div
  strong JID:
  br
  = @journal.jid
div
  strong Abbreviation:
  br
  = f.text_field :abbreviation, size: '25%'
div
  strong Name:
  br
  = f.text_field :name, size: '25%'
div
  strong Free Access:
  br
  = f.check_box :free_access
div
  strong Static Cover Image:
  br
  = f.check_box :static_cover_images, class: 'static_cover_image_enable'
div class='static_cover_image'
  - if @journal.cover_image.exists?
    = image_tag @journal.cover_image.url(:thumbnail)
    br
    italic Replace static cover image:
    br
    = f.file_field :cover_image, as: :file

  - else
    = f.file_field :cover_image, as: :file
**div class='rights_link'
  strong Rights Link
  br
  = f.check_box :rights_link_enabled, class: 'rights_link_enable'**
div class='rights_link_type'
  strong Rights Link Type:
  br
  - if @journal.rights_link_type == 'permission_direct'
    = radio_button_tag :rights_link_type, 'rights_link'
    | Rights Link
    = radio_button_tag :rights_link_type, 'permission_direct', true
    | Permission Direct
  - else
    = radio_button_tag :rights_link_type, 'rights_link', true
    | Rights Link
    = radio_button_tag :rights_link_type, 'permission_direct'
    | Permission Direct
div class='rights_link_template'
  strong Rights Link URL Template:
  br
  = f.text_area :rights_link_template, class: 'rights_link_template', size: '50%'
div class='issn'
  strong ISSN
  br
  = f.text_field :issn, size: '25%'
div class='rights_holder_name'
  strong Rights Holder Name
  br
  = f.text_field :rights_holder_name, size: '25%'
div
  strong Exclude From All Articles:
  br
  = f.check_box :exclude_from_all_articles
div
  strong Enabled:
  br
  = check_box_tag 'journal[enabled]', 1, @journal.disabled_at ? false : true
div
  strong Updated At:
  br
  = display_local_time @journal.updated_at
div
  strong Min iOS Version:
  br
  = f.text_field :ios_min_version, size: '25%'
div
  strong Min Android Version:
  br
  = f.text_field :android_min_version, size: '25%'
= f.submit "Update"

= link_to 'Back', dashboard_journals_path
```

Please provide a solution.

I tried using

```
update_button.trigger(:click)
```

But no help. Please Note: the div before the 'rights_link' div is hidden and shown in some cases.

Comment: Hello, I do not understand what do you mean by saying `no help`?

Comment: .trigger(:click) did not solve the error.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First, if you are testing an app don't use `#trigger`.  The important part of the error message that suggests using `#trigger` is "If you don't care about overlapping elements".  When testing an app you should care, since otherwise you're allowing the test to do things a user couldn't (if screen scraping or automating a process it's a different story).

The error explains what the issue is, you have elements that are overlapping each other, and can often be fixed by specifying a larger window size in your poltergeist driver configuration.  You can usually see why things are overlapping by calling `save_and_open_screenshot` right before the click step, and looking at the screenshot.  If the page is too narrow or two short you can increase the window size in the requisite direction.

```
Capybara.register_driver :poltergeist do |app|
  Capybara::Poltergeist::Driver.new(app, window_size: [1600, 1200])
end
```

Additionally you should not be using the `eq` matcher with `current_path` because it has no waiting/retrying behavior so your JS test will end up being flaky.  Instead you should use the `have_current_path` matcher provided by Capybara.  Also the way you're finding the update_button is slightly strange and if you want to keep it in a `let` block would be more understandable written as `let(:update_button) { find(:button, 'Update') }` although I would suggest just using `click_button` instead.

```
it 'should redirect to detail' do
  visit dashboard_journal_path @journal
  click_button 'Update'
  page.should have_current_path(dashboard_journals_path)
end
```